# Assign a categorie on a cell depending on strings

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

i will try to xplain what i would like to do
i got a huge file that report alarm text from different type of systems

i the first colum i got the alarm (1 line = 1 alarm text)
i would like to associate a categorie (on the 2nd column) depending on some words extract from the alarm text

eg : if the word aaaa is present in the alarm the categorie should be "A", if bbbb is present the categorie should be "B" ; .....

i got many categories , more than 50 ... and i want to be able to add new categorie if needed

i found a "solution" with this kind of formula

> `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Wafer not";BD2));"HANDLING";"UKN")`

BD2 is where y alarm text is stored

==> basically i have included a new formula inside the previous one to cover all categories

it looks like that (just an extract) : ;

> `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mixing";BD2));"CC MIXING ALARM";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("port";BD2));"LP ERROR";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mass flow";BD2));"MFC";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CC comm";BD2));"CC COMMUNICATION";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("unclear";BD2));"UNCLEARED ALARM";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("door";BD2));"COVER";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("wafer level sens";BD2));"WAFER LEVEL SENSOR";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tank A";BD2));"COOLING TANK";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tank B";BD2));"COOLING TANK";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("hdiw-unit";BD2));"HDIW UNIT";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("labyrinth";BD2));"LABYRINTH ERROR";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FAN";BD2));"FAN";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("handling";BD2));"HANDLING";IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("process has stopped";BD2));"PROCESS STOP";"UKN")))))))))))))`

==> but it's really ugly ;-) .... if if if if if if .....

i'm pretty sure something nicer and smarter might exist

if you have a idea to help me it would be great

thanks in advance for your help

regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is an array formula you can use:
`=INDEX(Table2[[#All],[category]],MAX(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[[#All],[word]],D2)),ROW(Table2[[#All],[word]]),"")))`

- `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[[#All],[word]],D2)),ROW(Table2[[#All],[word]]),"")` - search each `Word` in your text, returns row number if found, "" (empty string) if not found
- `MAX(IF(...))` - select the biggest number returned by `IF` (if multiple categories are matched, then last one is returned)
- `=INDEX(Table2[[#All],[category]],MAX(...))` - return category from the corresponding row
- it's an array formula, so you need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to insert it.

To use that, you need to convert your range containing keywords and categories to a table (insert - table), you might need to change table's name in your formula.

[image]